# Negate `.Where()` LINQ Expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I understand that you can do the following:

```
enumerable.Where(MethodGroup).DoSomething();
```

and that this achieves the same thing as:

```
enumerable.Where(x => MyMethod(x)).DoSomething();
```

However, I wish to achieve the inverse of this and to select the items where the method returns false. It is obvious how to do this for the second case:

```
enumerable.Where(x => !MyMethod(x)).DoSomething();
```

Yet, for the first, this is not the case as you cannot apply the `!` operator to a `MethodGroup`. Is it possible to achieve this sort of "`.WhereNot`" effect with `MethodGroups` in a similar fashion or do I have to roll my own (or use lambdas)?

Comment: What's the problem with using the lambda?

Comment: You can build a `WhereNot` but why would you want to do that? Just just a lambda.

Comment: Nothing particularly @TheLethalCoder, I just think that it's nicer to have some level of consistency with regards to using method groups or lambdas, even if there are no major benefits

Comment: @DavidG, yeah I know I could and if there's no inbuilt functionality to that I might do that and throw it into my utility library (along with my much loved IEnumerable.ForEach() function)

Comment: The exact same answer I recently got on the exact same question (which I deleted): the `!`-operator is defined for type `bool`, not for type `delegate`.

Comment: The problem you're now adding another layer of obfuscation to your code. Everyone will know what the lambda means, nobody will be quite sure what `WhereNot` does though.

Comment: You can create your own extension method ( `WhereNot` ) which will behave as you described, but IMO it is better to use negation sign ( `!` ) after all.

Comment: @m.rogalski you can't negate a method group sadly

Comment: @JamesHughes I misunderstood this then. But still the same thing applies, that you can create an extension method to achieve this.

Comment: You could simply inverse the logic of `MyMethod` to be a `NotMyMethod`. E.g. `enumerable.Where(x => IsSomething(x))` would become `enumerable.Where(IsNotSomething)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a helper method:

```
public static Func<T, bool> Not<T>(Func<T, bool> method) 
{
    return x => !method(x);
}
```

Then the usage will be very similar to what you want:

```
someEnumerable.Where(Not(MyMethod)).DoSomething();
```

Comment: or you can use everything together like `public static IEnumerable<T> WhereNot<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<T, bool> predicate)
        {
            return enumerable.Where(e => !predicate(e));
        }`

Comment: The OP wanted to do something like `Where(!MyMethod)`. This answer achieves that, but using words instead of symbols.

Comment: Whilst not the answer I'm actually going with (I've just written my own `WhereNot` function as I believe this is clearer), this answer achieves exactly what I was asking so is the one I'm accepting.

Comment: This is where `ruby` shines in comparison. A simple `reject` can be built into linq , with it being a simple inversion of the where predicate, as above.

Answer (score 6):

There is no direct way to do this from the set of methods provided in LINQ. Even if you somehow achieve that, it won't be an efficient one.

Like you contemplated, a new one needs to be made like this

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> WhereNot<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    return source.Where(x => !predicate(x));
}
```

and use it like

```
var inverseResult = lst.WhereNot(MyMethod);
```

Comment: Why not just `return source.Where(i => !predicate(i));`?

Comment: I mean within your method, there's no need for a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Except to achieve this

```
yourList.Except(yourList.Where(MethodGroup)).DoSomething();
```

Comment: Will this do two calls to the collection instead of one?

Comment: Seems like not a great practice. You iterate same array twice.

Comment: Felicitari for a nice solution, Liviu. +1

Comment: Whilst an informative answer, I can't mark it as accepted as I'd like to avoid double-iteration if possible. Thank you though.

Comment: this should be illegal.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there are no built in ways to do this so either roll your own solution. Or just use the lambda which I personally don't see anything wrong with:

```
someList.Where(x => !MyMethod(x)).DoSomething();
```

This is also better than [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43609098/4631427) as it doesn't iterate over the collection twice.

Note just using the lambda makes your code more explicit than rolling your own method or using some workaround. In this case, for something as simple as this, I think it would be better to stick with the lambda and not add unnecessary obfuscation to your code.

Comment: He already said in the question that he knows he can do this, hence my workaround answer

Comment: C&P from question? -1

Comment: @LiviuBoboia I know and my answer to the question Can I do this on the method group? Is no, just use a lambda or roll your own solution.

Comment: @Toshi The answer is no you can't do this with a built in. Nothing wrong with a no answer. If I hadn't have copied the code into my answer would you still have downvoted?

Comment: Just using inline lambdas is the easiest to understand and most portable query you can have since it does not rely on another extension method that people might not know and which you need to import properly first in order to be able to use it. And when compiled, this actually results in less overall overhead.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder yes because your answer would be just a comment

Comment: @Toshi No it is still an answer, I can't find the relevant meta post at the moment but the consensus is, if the answer is no it is okay for an answer. And that applies in this case.

Comment: Rejecting `WhereNot` with this reasoning only makes sense if you also reject `Where(Method)`.